# Extending Eclipse's JavaEditor (to act like Vim/change KeyListener)

Tags: java, eclipse, vim, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

### Introduction a.k.a. what do I intend to do

*feel free to skip this part, no real information is comprised in here*

Because of the lack of a good, free (as in speech) `vim`-Mode for the otherwise excellent JavaEditor in Eclipse(3.4), I'm thinking about writing one. The available solutions are:

- [ViPlugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/): commercial and not good (e.g. no `vim` `text-objects`, such as `daW`)
- [VimPlugin](http://vimplugin.org/): new editor, not the power of the built in JavaEditor
- see [SO: *Painless* integration of Eclipse with Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597117/painless-integration-of-eclipse-with-vim) : nothing really good turned up

(However feel free to mention **other** solutions than the ones above which could help me.)

In my opinion, it's the wrong way of writing a completely new editor based on [`TextEditor`](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/editors/text/TextEditor.html), because you will then loose the cool features the standard JavaEditor gives you for free (such as 'organize imports', 'refactor menu', ...).

I'm thinking of a 'skin' to the normal JavaEditor which behaves like `vim`, everything else should be unchanged.

### Now the questions

- How can I detect if a [`IWorkbenchPart`](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPart.html) given by [`IPartListener.partActivated()`](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPartListener.html#partActivated(org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPart)) is the JavaEditor?
- How can I then replace JavaEditor's [`KeyListener`](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/KeyListener.html); something like the [`ITextViewerExtension.prependVerifyKeyListener`](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/ITextViewerExtension.html#prependVerifyKeyListener(org.eclipse.swt.custom.VerifyKeyListener)) is needed?
- Is this a good way to go on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am the developer of something you might be looking for. It is still under heavy development and does not have all features you are looking for, but I am working hard on it and I am always open for feature and enhancement requests.

The plugin is called [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net).
It is FOSS and follows the principles you describe, although I don't think it is much more powerful than the ViPlugin at the moment. But as I said, I am constantly working on it and try to respond fast to feature requests. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use the VI plugin from [here](http://www.satokar.com/viplugin/) (note: this link is down as of the time of writing and I'm hoping it'll be back soon). This works very well indeed and ties in very well with the coding/refactoring capabilities of Eclipse (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495268/any-good-tutorial-for-moving-from-eclipse-to-vim)).

So you may want to try that link (if it comes up!) before you embark on engineering your own solution :-)

Comment: The author switched domains.  It's now at http://www.viplugin.com.  I highly recommend this plugin.  My fingers don't do anything but Vi.

Comment: Ah. Thx for the heads up re domain change

Comment: Vi Plugin was mentioned in the original post, as its a commercial solution and doesnt support even the simpelst vim-features it doesnt solve the original problem.

Comment: As theomega said, ViPlugin is just not good enough and it is not free (as is speech) which is very important to me

Answer (score 0):

I try Vrapper, it's comfortable. got vim function in eclipse, naver lost original function