# Pointers for developing in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

So, tonight I just installed the ubuntu os onto my computer; I've used windows for my whole life, but I wanted to try something new.

I just wanted to know a few things, although they may be very simple questions;

1. What application do you suggest I install?
   (I've been using Visual Studio on Windows, so anything comparable?)
2. Does ubuntu support developing in C#?
   (I'm fairly new to the developing world, so I don't know these things..)
3. Does anyone know of some good videos or tutorials for what I've asked?
   (Maybe like a "Hello, World!" tutorial or something.)

Thanks for your time, and for reading through my questions :)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're looking for an IDE, personally I like NetBeans. I don't think it has C# support though.
2. Yes. You might want to check out MonoDevelop, which apparently is a C# IDE for linux.
3. No

Though I think you should try a text-based editor such as vim, and try to learn some of the great command-line tools available in Linux. It's a steeper learning curve than using GUI tools, but you won't regret learning it.

Answer (score 0):

It's super old now, but I remember this book being *extremely* helpful back in the day:

[Beginning Linux Programming](http://www.assoc-amazon.com/e/ir?t=&l=as2&o=1&a=1874416680)

As for editors....get good at emacs. Keyboard-based, text-mode beats clicky GUI stuff every time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a fair number of IDE's out there.  I'd ignore the emacs/vi comments if you need a true IDE since it will take a fair bit of work to get them to do half of what a real IDE does.  If you plan on working across multiple platforms, get an IDE that works everywhere like Eclipse.

As honeyp)t mentions, Mono is the C# equivalent in the OSS world.

And instead of a video, try a good book to learn development on Linux (don't look for a book on Ubuntu, that's too specific and will lead you astray).

Comment: mono is the .net equivalent. c# is the same between the two

Comment: Can you give an example of something a "real IDE" does that Emacs can't?

Comment: @drysdam: I wouldn't touch that holy war with a 10 foot pole :-)

Comment: @knittl: thanks.  I've been avoiding the dark side too much to keep up with the right lingo.

Comment: If you aren't prepared to back up an negative statement like that, maybe you shouldn't make it.

Comment: @drysdam: There are long Q's on comparing various editors (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346820).  When it comes down to it, emacs is good at everything and great at nothing.  If you're doing development work, especially coming from a windows environment, I think you're better off with an IDE rather than a highly extendable text editor.

Comment: I dunno. I watch my colleagues laboriously mousing over to every function, trying to cobble Makefile-like arrangements hidden inside of IDE configuration windows and generally spending more time fighting the GUI than doing actual work.  I would agree that an IDE is more *familiar* to a Windows user but I don't agree that they'd be *better off*.